# What is a maintenance free battery?

Tags: batteries

I have searched on Google but can't find anything. Could anyone please tell me what a maintenance free battery is? Perhaps some examples of maintenance free batteries and any good sites for further research could be provided.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=battery+maintenance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term "Maintenance Free Battery" is typically applied to sealed lead-acid batteries such as used for UPS units.

Traditional lead-acid batteries for automobiles needed the battery electrolyte topped up from time to time with distilled water, whereas the maintenance free ones neither need, nor support such maintenance.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering could you please providing me some example of "Maintenance Free Battery"

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="maintenance+free+battery"&tbm=isch

Comment: @Anido Ghosh, Does Lithium and Ni-Cd battery are Maintenance Free Battery?  Thank you so much for answering Anindo bhai.

Comment: @Pritesh No, the term is typically applied only to Sealed Lead Acid (SLA) batteries.

Answer (score 2):

mantainance free bateries are the sealed ones, which you can't add clean water+sulphuric acid except in some cases i've seen people perforates the battery to reuse them mostly for a short time-period results as the sealed batteries have thinner lead plates which consume as fast as the chemicals so it would give you a margin of a months? until you replace them for newer ones